# Factory class vs FromObject() method

Tags: .net, design-patterns

In my application I have a class that is used to deserialize some response into objects.
I have the Notification class and another class NotificationUnmarshaller. This has only one method:

```
 public IList<Notification> UnMarshal(PullResponse pullResponse)
```

I want to refactor this class into a public static method in Notification class. Something like:

```
public class Notification
{
    //members
    public static IList<Notification> FromResponse(PullResponse response}
    {
         //unmarshal
    }
}
```

In this a good design pattern? Is there any advantage of having a class with one single method to deserialize the response? Is the FromObject(...) method pattern a good one?

Answer (score 1):

If all you are doing in this class is returning a deserialized object then I'd say no.

A generic template method works better for XML Serialization.

See:  [generic-xml-serializer-class](http://www.rhyous.com/2010/04/29/generic-xml-serializer-class-for-c-and-an-xml-serialization-usage-example/)